# How can I ask the user for the account number and the amount to deposit in the run deposit method

Tags: java, methods, menu

How can I ask the user for the account number and the amount to deposit in the run deposit method. Is this the best way to tackle this. I am not too sure on how to do a menu in java and have tried to do adapt some i have looked at.

Appreciate any help / advice

cheers

```
package Week8;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankTester {

    public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Customer customer1 = new Customer("Jim", "Brown", "12/1265");

        CurrentAccount currentAccount1 = new CurrentAccount(0.0, customer1, AccountType.personal, 25.0);

        ArrayList<CurrentAccount> bank = new ArrayList<CurrentAccount>();
        bank.add(currentAccount1);

        printMenu(bank);

    }

    private static void printMenu(ArrayList<CurrentAccount> bank) {
        System.out.println("\n1)Deposit\n2)Withdraw\n2)Month End\n3)Quit");
        System.out.println("Please Select and an Option: ");







        int input = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        int currentAccountPos = -1;
        switch (input) {
        case (1):
            Deposit(currentAccountPos, bank);
            break;

        case (2):
            Withdraw(currentAccountPos, bank);
            break;

        case (3):
            MonthEnd(currentAccountPos, bank);
            break;

        case (0):
            Quit(currentAccountPos, bank);
            break;

        }

    }

    private static void Quit(int currentAccountPos, ArrayList<CurrentAccount> bank) {
        System.exit(0);

    }

    private static void Withdraw(int currentAccountPos, ArrayList<CurrentAccount> bank) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private static void MonthEnd(int currentAccountPos, ArrayList<CurrentAccount> bank) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static void Deposit(int currentAccountPos, ArrayList<CurrentAccount> bank) // this method here {

        }
}
```

Comment: Any advice @azurefrog

Comment: Not really. I don't have the time today to concentrate on answering questions;  I'm just cleaning up syntax in questions in between builds.

Comment: Cheers anyway bud appreciate it if ya have a spare minute to look over it if you could no problem if your can't

Answer (score 0):

In the case (1) try this.

```
case (1):
{
    System.out.println("Please enter amount to deposit: ");
    int amount = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Amount - " + amount);
    Deposit(currentAccountPos, bank);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Cheers that worked how would I ask the user for the account number would it be something similar

Comment: would you not have to add  code into the actual methods  to be able to add more functions to them                                                                                  public static void Deposit(int currentAccountPos, ArrayList<CurrentAccount> bank) // this method here {

        }

Comment: also how could you display the balance after it has been added